# Identify elements on Angular based site for WebDriver

Tags: angular, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

There is an `Angular` based site, which doesn't use unique names/ids for elements. `XPATH` of elements are not permanent on page, so `WebDriver` based test has to be changed after each modification on site. How could I manage elements on this page without use of `XPATH`?

Comment: Code trials and relevant `HTML` please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, follow the [Page Object pattern](http://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects) to at least have the locators defined in one place - inside page objects. This would help to address the changing UI.

Other things to consider:

- avoid [using XPaths altogether](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide#never-use-xpath), why:

> - It's the slowest and most brittle locator strategy of all
> - Markup is
>     very easily subject to change and therefore xpath locators require a
>     lot of maintenance
> - xpath expressions are unreadable and very hard to
>     debug

- do not rely on the structure of the page or relative position of elements to each other
- avoid repeating locators or parts of the locators - the more you repeat the more you will need to change when the design/UI changes
- remember that elements like `div` or `span` are just containers - using them inside locators is rarely justified
- make your locators readable and based on data - not design or layout. For instance, don't use Bootstrap layout-oriented classes like `col-md-4` or `col-xs-6`
- follow some of the common best practices suggested in these articles:

  - [Writing reliable locators for Selenium and WebDriver tests](https://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2013/09/26/writing-reliable-locators-for-selenium-and-webdriver-tests/)
  - [Using Locators](http://www.protractortest.org/#/locators)

Answer (score 0):

Simple question, simple answer:

If you cannot use names/ids and do not want to use xpath, you are limited to *css selector, class name, tag name* - and (partial) link text when dealing with links.

Maybe this [article helps](https://seleniumhq.github.io/docs/start.html#locating_elements).

Answer (score 0):

**Don't rely on JUST one selector method!**

You can use any of the other findElement() options such as cssSelector, name, tagName, etc. And more to the point, you don't have to use them singly. In other words, go as far as you can via one method and then switch to another. Here is a Java example of starting with XPath and finishing with css:

```
private final String xGrid = "//div[contains(@class,'lists-grid')]/div[contains(@class,'ui-grid')]";
private final String xGridWrapper = "/div[contains(@class,'ui-grid-contents-wrapper')]";

@FindBy(xpath = xGridScopeSubscriptions + xGridWrapper)
private List<WebElement> gridRecordList;

public void clickGridSubscriptionActionEditByRow(int row) {
    int totalColumns = gridRecordList.size();
    int actionColumn = getColumnIdByHeader("Action");

    WebElement actionCell = gridRecordList.get((totalColumns * row) + actionColumn);
    WebElement editButton = actionCell.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.subscription-edit-btn"));

    editButton.click();
}
```

Mind you, this is kind of a hodgepodge of different things, but I hope you get the idea.

Start with Strings to define key markers in the code. Concatenate the strings to assign a WebElement variable for starting points. Then in methods, using the starting point, do findElements() from there based on different selectors.

You can even do it all in one shot.

```
private WebElement deleteIcon driver.findElement(By.id("name-list")).findElement(By.cssSelector("div.grid-ui div.grid-cell")).findElement(By.xpath("./td[3]/i[contains(@class,'fa-trash')]"));
```

*I know you said that the ID's are not stable, but I just wanted to give you an example of stringing together different methods of finding elements to reach your final goal.*

Comment: I know, that there are multiple selectors, but it is hard to maintain, how it changes.

Comment: There will always be change in software. All you can hope for is to make adjusting to change easier down the road. That is why I gave the suggestion of using strings to hold paths to key points in the webpage. For me, a grid is a grid is a grid. So I made strings of how to get to the start of the grid, then from there all the wrapper code. In my real automation there is also strings for finding a column, finding a cell within a column, how to identify headers.  These are all common concepts and when the UI changes, I just update each section as needed.